# vue3 laravel show data in console but not in table

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to laravel and vue.js and I'm trying to display some data. when I do console.log in onMounted it returns data but when I try do display it, it says no data. I use DataTable to display my data.

Here is my controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $landing = Landing::all();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'List Data Post',
            'data' => $landing
        ], 200);
    }
```

My script

```
<script setup>
import axios from 'axios';
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

let landings = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
   axios.get('/api/adminLanding')
   .then(response => {
      landings.value = response.data.data
      console.log(landings)
   }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response.data)
   })
})
</script>
```

My tbody

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="(landing, index) in landings" :key="index">
      <td>{{ landing.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ landing.updated_at }}</td>
      <td>{{ landing.admin }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

My Console.log

RefImpl {__v_isShallow: false, dep: Set(1), __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: Array(1), _value: Proxy(Array)}
dep
:
Set(0) {w: 0, n: 0, size: 0}
__v_isRef
:
true
__v_isShallow
:
false
_rawValue
:
Array(1)
0
:
admin
:
"Yaa"
created_at
:
"2023-03-03T07:22:34.000000Z"
id
:
6
image
:
"20230303142234.jpg"
name
:
"Buthuk"
updated_at
:
"2023-03-03T07:22:34.000000Z"
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
length
:
1
[[Prototype]]
:
Array(0)
_value
:
Proxy(Array) {0: {…}}
value
:
(...)
[[Prototype]]
:
Object

Comment: What exactly does the console show?

Comment: I've edited my post and add the console show